# oracle sql concat query title

Tags: sql, oracle

For my course of databases I got home some sql excercises. One of them is to result this:

```
WHO EARNS WHAT
_____________________
MR MARTIN EARNS 1250 A MONTH
```

Now I got the way to select the right data as in:

```
SELECT 'MR ' || ENAME || ' EARNS ' || SAL || ' A MONTH ' FROM EMP WHERE ENAME = 'MARTIN';
```

But what I can't find is how to put the title on top of the query? Can someone help me on that?

Comment: Good question as being new on stack community! Appreciable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AS "WHO EARNS WHAT"`

like this:

```
SELECT 'MR ' || ENAME || ' EARNS ' || SAL || ' A MONTH ' 
AS "WHO EARNS WHAT"
FROM EMP WHERE ENAME = 'MARTIN';
```